# Adding a boolean type field to a table using SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to add a boolean field to a table using SQL however I'm not getting anywhere. The query I am using to try and add the field is:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST
ADD "NewField" BOOLEAN
```

When running this it will display the error `Invalid use of keyword`. I'm trying to add this field to a paradox database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What SQL engine? Oracle, MS SQL Server, DB2, MySQL, Postgresql etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no Boolean in SQL - use a `bit` column instead.

Answer (score 0):

double quote = postgres? The table names with capital letters may need double quotes as well.

> alter table "TEST" add "NewField" boolean;

may work....